# How does Electron proxy URLs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy, electron

I created a small server which, for now, just outputs the `request.url`:

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
function onRequest(clientRequest, clientResponse) {
    console.log(clientRequest.url);
}
```

Using the Electron APIs we can set up a proxy: to proxy all the urls through this server.

So, I'm running my server on `localhost:8080` and use the [`--proxy-server http://localhost:8080`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md#--proxy-serveraddressport) to redirect the traffic through my proxy server. This allows me to change some snippets in the HTML and only then render it in Electron.

When I access `http://ionicabizau.net` the `request.url` on the server side is `http://ionicabizau.net`.

How come that we can override the request url in such a way? What does Electron in the background?

First I thought that it just has to do with appending it like this:

> `http://localhost:8080/http://ionicabizau.net`

But actually, that arrives on the server like `/http://ionicabizau.net` (notice the first slash).

What's the magic that Electron does to change the url of the `request` object?

Answer (score 0):

When Electron (or anything else) makes an HTTP request, it connects to the target server and port and sends a message like the following:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

Most servers interpret this as an HTTP request for the full URL `http://www.example.com/`. When you specify a proxy server, that affects what server the HTTP client connects to, but it doesn't change the content of the request (so the requested URL is still `http://www.example.com/`).

So there's really nothing special that Electron needs to do to "override" the request URL... any HTTP client specifies the request URL as part of the message it sends to the server, and this is independent of which server that message is sent to.

Comment: Yes, the `host` can be changed, but how can the `url` field be changed in that way? The `req.url` is supposed to be in `/path/name?query=string` format, but when proxying via Electron, the whole url appears in `req.url`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, perhaps I misunderstood your question. This can be reproduced with Node by sending `GET http://www.example.com HTTP/1.1`, but it seems unlikely to me that Electron would send that. (That would be atypical.)